Flutter build for iOS simulator
I'm trying to test flutter app using Azure DevOps and Appium. My CI/CD pipeline contains 2 major jobs - build app & run tests. First job creates .app file and passes it as an artifact to the second job. To achieve this I have to launch iOS simulator and build with flutter run. Those actions take significant amount of time and I'm wondering is there a way to build iOS app without a need to create simulator.
I've tried flutter build ios --debug --no-codesign but the resulting app is incompatible with the iOS simulator.

In case if someone finds this question by googling.
The solution was replacing the --debug flag with --simulator flag:
build ios --simulator --no-codesign

I'm not sure why you would try to run a built ios app on a simulator as it's not possible. You can only run ios apps on the ios-simulator as Debug (Runner).
If you want to test flight on physical a device or upload the ios file, you may need the IPA (.ipa) file.
Here's how to do it:
First build the basic ios app (outputs .app folder)
flutter build ios --release --no-codesign

Select the release profile for ios runners
xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace ios/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -configuration Release

Now this is a tricky part.
export IOS_DEV_TEAM=<your ios dev team>
export IOS_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_UUID=<your ios provisioning profile id>
xcodebuild -workspace ios/Runner.xcworkspace -scheme Runner -configuration Release DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=$IOS_DEV_TEAM -sdk 'iphoneos' -destination 'generic/platform=iOS' -archivePath build-output/app.xcarchive PROVISIONING_PROFILE=$IOS_PROVISIONING_PROFILE_UUID clean archive CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="Apple Distribution: <Your company name>"

You've to create a iOS dev team using AppStoreConnect and then from XCode you've to create a provisioning profile. If you already done that before,

you can find dev team id from: https://developer.apple.com/account#MembershipDetailsCard
Here's the way to create/get provisional id: https://developer.apple.com/help/account/manage-profiles/create-an-app-store-provisioning-profile/

Finally, export the ipa archive:
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath build-output/app.xcarchive -exportPath build-output/ios -exportOptionsPlist ios/ExportOptions.plist

You can find the built .ipa file in build-output/ios/<your app name>.ipa
Now, you can upload this ipa file for test flight using Transporter. And install in physical iOS device

This answer is not even close to the question. Building for real device is a well documented process while I need it for the ios simulator.
